# Jquery post option value to PHP

Tags: php, jquery

How can I post data using Jquery from selected data to the PHP?

HTML code:

```
<select id="test" title="test" class="test">
  <option value="1">1
  <option value="2">2
  <option value="3">3
  <option value="4">4
  <option value="5">5
 </select>
```

Jquery:

```
$('.18').click(function(event) {
  var test_s = $('#test').val();
  $('.opc_mfont').load("index.php?x=18&fid=<?=$fid;?>&mid=<?=$mid;?>&data=' + test_s +'");
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

All the data was successfully post to PHP and MySql query except ' + test_s + ' at the and of jquery load().

I was tested that data received from select fields with "alert(test_s);" and the alert message show up with correct data on it. But I can't send "var test_s" to PHP using jquery load(). How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### read

from jQuery .load():

*The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed.*

read here: http://api.jquery.com/load/

#### code

untested, probably something like this:

```
$('.opc_mfont').load("index.php?x=18&fid=<?=$fid;?>&mid=<?=$mid;?>", {'data':test_s});
```

Comment: This is the solution for my problem. Thanks Adam.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is your string:

```
"index.php?x=18&fid=<?=$fid;?>&mid=<?=$mid;?>&data=' + test_s +'"
```

That's not string concatenation - you're mixing your string delimiters.  You want:

```
"index.php?x=18&fid=<?=$fid;?>&mid=<?=$mid;?>&data=" + test_s
```

Answer (score 2):

You mixed up single and double quotes:

```
$('.18').click(function(event) {
  var test_s = $('#test').val();
  $('.opc_mfont').load('index.php?x=18&fid=<?=$fid;?>&mid=<?=$mid;?>&data=' + test_s);
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```